# get the exact XML, which is send to Soap Service

Tags: spring-boot, soap, jaxb

from our application we are calling a soap service like below

```
res = (CreateResponse) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(getWebServiceTemplate()
                    .marshalSendAndReceive(soapUrl, req, new headers(msgHeader)));
```

now i want to see the actual request `xml` which is send to the `SOAP` url.

> soapUrl - target soap url

> req - it is an object of a class `CreateRequest`

> msgHeader - it is an object `MsgHeader`

Because, currently we are getting an error

> ns0:MsgErrorCd Description="REQUEST STRUCTURE INVALID"

So the team , which maintains the SOAP service, need the input XML,
Could you pls help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `application.properties` file, added the below lines, now the request xml is getting printed in the console.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
```